# I can't find the settings in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, system-settings, gnome-control-center

This is a bit weird as I cannot find the settings window at all. I don't know the exact name of the default settings app, so I am unable to install it from apt or snap.

EDIT: running

```
apt policy gnome-control-center
```

in the terminal gave me output

```
gnome-control-center:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 1:3.32.2-0ubuntu1.1
Version table:
 1:3.32.2-0ubuntu1.1 500
    500 http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 
Packages
 1:3.32.1-1ubuntu4 500
    500 http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
```

EDIT: My problem was not with settings not working, but it being non-existent. It is solved now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the results of `apt policy gnome-control-center` the GNOME desktop Settings application (the Settings app which has a white gear and red wrench icon) which is installed by default in Ubuntu is not currently installed on your system. To install the Settings app open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

To show more information on the Settings app before you install it run the following command:

```
apt show gnome-control-center
```